# Yii без activeform

Tags: yii2, yii

как можно передавать в контроллер переменные с формы методом пост - без использование activemodel. Так как планирую переехать на другой фреймворк, стараюсь без расширений yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В activeform в качестве action используется текущий адрес страницы. Соответственно, чтобы их не использовать, достаточно писать форму с action на текущую страницу.
Например, если страница расположена по адресу

```
http://example.com/path/to/page.php
```

И имеет код для форм такой:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Login') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

То эквивалентный без ActiveForm будет вот такой:

```
<form action="" id="login-form">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Код примерный, взят из экзамплов с документации, но суть, думаю, ясна.